# aggregate not showing correct results

Tags: r, aggregate-functions

I have a dataset data1 as shown below

```
       Id    Results
       1232  Az
       1232  Ca
       1223  Hi
       1223  Az
       8477  Ca
       8477  Ca
```

I used aggregate function to group these based on Id,

```
       aggregate(Results~ Id, data=data1, FUN=head,1)
```

I was expecting

```
        Id      Results
        1232    Az,Ca,Hi
        1223    Hi, Az 
        8477    Ca, Ca
```

I am seeing

```
        Id      Results
        1232    Az
        1223    Az
        1223    Ca
```

Comment: Can't replicate this. I see `structure(list(Id = c(1223L, 1232L, 8477L), Results = structure(c(3L, 
1L, 2L), .Label = c("Az", "Ca", "Hi"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Id", 
"Results"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")`.

Comment: @TyVoss I echo Jbaums.  It is not able reproducible with your code.  I get only a single element for Results

Comment: @TyVoss why would you expect `Hi` in group `1232`? I think you're probably after this: `aggregate(Results ~ Id, d, paste0, collapse=',')`.

Comment: @TyVoss Can you show the `str` of the dataset or better will be the `dput` as jbaums showed.  It may be a list column

Comment: @jbaums,@akrun I re ran the aggregate function again and you all are right Iam just seeing single value, I updated my question

Comment: @jbaums  `aggregate(Results ~ Id, d, paste0, collapse=',')` was exactly what I was trying to do, you are awesome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single value per group is what you should expect if the function you pass to `aggregate` is `head(x, 1)`.

If instead you want a string of comma-separated values that belong to each group, you can use:

```
aggregate(Results ~ Id, d, paste0, collapse=',')

#     Id Results
# 1 1223   Hi,Az
# 2 1232   Az,Ca
# 3 8477   Ca,Ca
```